# What are the differences of using value proxies for my entities instead of entity proxies?

Tags: gwt

So far  i understand that  i will have no more need to define an @version field in my entitites and no more need to use an entity locator. And for value proxies i will have to usenormal editors. Any other diffrences, advantages, disadvantages? What about in the context of using request factory in conjunction with spring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that with `EntityProxy`, the client can send a diff of changes rather than the entire object graph. This is made possible because `EntityProxy`s have an *identity*, so the server can fetch the identity from the datastore and then apply the diff/patch sent from the client, and only then the entity will be passed to your service methods.

With `ValueProxy` you basically have an equivalent of GWT-RPC: the object is reconstructed from scratch on the server, and not associated with your datastore (in the case of JPA for instance, it's not *attached* to the session). Depending on your datastore API, this can make things more complex to handle in your service methods.

Other than that, you'll also lose the `EntityProxyChange` events.